# How to compute $\int_{1}^{\infty} dx \sin \beta x e^{-\alpha x}x^n $or express it in terms of special functions?

Tags: integration, special-functions

Compute $\int_{1}^{\infty} dx \sin \beta x e^{-\alpha x}x^n $, where $\beta ,\alpha >0$, $n$ is an integer (positive or negative).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: You could write it in terms of incomplete Gamma functions, but in general it can only be evaluated numerically.

Answer (score 2):

The integral can be rephrased to
$$I_n(z)= Im \int_1^{+\infty}e^{zx} x^n dx$$
where $z= -\alpha + i\beta$ with $\alpha,\beta >0$.
Now observe that
$$I_0(z)= Im \int_1^{+\infty}e^{zx}  dx= -Im \frac{e^z}{z} \:.$$
On the other hand
$$\frac{d^n}{dz^n}I_0(z)= Im \int_1^{+\infty}x^n e^{zx}  dx = I_n(z)\:.$$
In summary,
$$\int_1^{+\infty}\sin(\beta x) e^{-\alpha x} x^n dx= Im \left.\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\right|_{z= -\alpha + i \beta} \frac{e^z}{z} = Im\:   e^z \left.\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {{n}\choose{k}} k! z^{-(k+1)}\right|_{z= -\alpha + i \beta}$$

Answer (score 1):

Deriving with respect to $\alpha$ $n$ times gets rid of that annoying $x^n$

$\int_1^\infty\sin(\beta x)e^{-\alpha x}x^n dx= (-1)^n\big(\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\big)^n\int_1^\infty\sin(\beta x)e^{-\alpha x}dx$

Now lets define the following integrals

$I_{\sin} (\alpha,\beta)=\int_1^\infty\sin(\beta x)e^{-\alpha x}dx $

$I_{\cos} (\alpha,\beta)=\int_1^\infty\cos(\beta x)e^{-\alpha x}dx $

and define also this

$I(\alpha,\beta)=I_{\cos} + iI_{\sin}=\int_1^\infty [\cos(\beta x) +i\sin(\beta x)]e^{-\alpha x}dx=\int_1^\infty e^{-\alpha x + i\beta x }dx$

This integral is a simple exponential integrals and it converges for $\alpha>0$

$I (\alpha,\beta)=-\frac{e^{-\alpha + i\beta}}{-\alpha + i\beta}$

To get $I_{\sin}$ we just need to calculate the imaginary part of $I$

$I_{\sin} (\alpha,\beta) = \Im I (\alpha,\beta)= 
\frac{\alpha \sin\beta - \beta \cos \beta}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}e^{-\alpha}$

This means that you can write the original integral as

$\int_1^\infty\sin(\beta x)e^{-\alpha x}x^n dx=(-1)^{n}\big(\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\big)^n\Big[\frac{\alpha \sin\beta - \beta \cos \beta}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}e^{-\alpha}\Big]$

And I think you can stop here because deriving is just a mechanical task, and the result will be ugly (lots of sums coefficients and binomial coefficients)